# Is it possible to put the projection of a map of a layout in a text label in a layout in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer

I would like to be able to have a text label in a print designer with the information of the projection of a map in QGIS. That way, if I change the projection of a project, I would change that information within the layout.

I think I've seen a variable map_src, but I can not find a way to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN QGIS 2.18. you can solve the problem if you are familiar with a bit of python. The function used in this can be found here in the docomentation.

- When creating a new label go to "insert an expression"
- Change to the "function editor tab and click new file
- insert the code below and hit "Load"
- go back to "expression" and insert  `show_crs(" ")`
- Resulöt will be as seen in the image.

You can fine-tune the strings if needed.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import * 
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def show_crs(val, feature, parent):
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

    epsg = canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().postgisSrid() # yields the EPSG Code 
    #short = canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().projectionAcronym()  # yields the short version 
    prj_string = canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().toProj4() # yields a 
    #map = canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().toWkt() # yields a WKT string 
    crs_string = "%s %s" %(prj_string.split("+")[1], prj_string.split("+")[2])
    map = "EPSG: %s \n Projektion: %s" % (epsg, crs_string)
    return map
```

[image]

Comment: @EmilioAbad glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it exists in QGIS 3.2. In fact, this function was added in QGIS 3.0: [check Expressions in QGIS 3.0 changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-item-variables-expression-function-inside-compositions). You need to insert a text box and there you can add expression:

```
@project_crs
```

[image]

and the projection will be added on the map. If you need more details, you can add this expression to the above one:

```
@project_crs_definition
```

Which will give you the CSR and its definition:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb, but I forgot to specify that I use version 2.18 of QGIS. But the answer I will keep in mind for the future.
Thank you very much

Comment: @EmilioAbad unfortunately, it is unavailable in QGIS 2.18. This function was added in QGIS 3.0: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-item-variables-expression-function-inside-compositions. Search for `@project_crs` and `@project_crs_definition`